# Duplicate mails in unread mail view of Windows Live Mail

Tags: windows-live-mail

When I get new mail and go to the "unread email" quick view I always see two version of the email, even though I definitely have only one such version in the inbox itself. Further, viewing the message via inbox usually marks only one of these copies as read, or sometimes none at all.

I have no custom filters defined that could cause duplication.

Any idea what's going on?

PS This is the new version (2011).

Comment: I have the very same issue. But it does extend not only to "unread mail" but also to "unread from contacts"(and probably every view option under it quick views too). I believe this is due the way Gmail labels work under Windows Live Mail 2011. If you hover the cursor over each duplicate mail you'll see one copy reads inbox, another reads all mail (another might read priority inbox, if it's enabled). I don't know who's end is responsible (Windows Live Client or Gmail) but I've been unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

"All mail" is a virtual view across actual folders in Gmail, so it will contain duplicates of mail in other folders.  The "Quick View" isn't smart enough to filter these duplicates and it appears there is no way to exclude folders from a Quick View.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your GMail account. Click on the sprocket icon in upper right and select Settings. Go to the Labels tab in your settings and UNCHECK the Starred, Important, and All Mail labels so that they do not show up for IMAP.
Finally, go to your Windows Live Mail and right click on your Gmail account and select Download All Folders. This will re-sync your folders and the duplicate emails will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my particular issue after right clicking 'Important' and choosing 'Hide this folder from list'

I would suggest checking which other folders in view, other than inbox are showing unread mail and hiding from list if you do not require them.